# Overriding file in bash in one pipe

Tags: bash, pipe, cat

The result of `cat file1 | cat > file1` is empty file1.

The result of `head file1 | cat > file1` is empty file1 as well.

Of course, a real pipe is intended to have more steps - tools and operations inside.

Is any way to save transformed read content?

The real case is `source .env && cat file1 | envsubst > file1`

Comment: Don't write to the same file you are reading.

Comment: Depending on the real transformations you are doing, maybe there's a possibility, but it depends on the tools that you use. With `cat` and `head`, there's no alternative.

Comment: Using extra software you can have a chance. Try with `sponge` (`moreutils`). But the general rule keeps valid: avoid writing to the same file you are reading.

Comment: Read this great link: [“In-place” editing of files](https://backreference.org/2011/01/29/in-place-editing-of-files/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, but correct answer is:

`cat file1 | envsubst | sponge file1`

This (from Veda) is the wrong usage of sponge

`cat file1 | envsubst | sponge | cat > file1`

Answer (score 0):

The only option is something like `(head file1 | cat > tmp_file) && mv tmp_file file1`.  In other words, you have to write to a temporary file and *then* replace the original file with the temporary.

Fundamentally bash has to open all the files and pipes before it starts `exec`ing each of the stages in the pipeline.  Once it has opened your output file for overwrite it is, er, overwritten.

Answer (score -1):

Sponge does that for you. You need to install it separately though, it is not usually included in the os.

```
cat test | sponge | cat > test
```

Will leave you with the contents that were originally in file "test".

To get sponge in Ubuntu or Redhat, you need to install package `moreutils`.

Comment: This might result in an empty file as well. There is still a race condition because of the redirection. Use `sponge` correctly: `cat test ... | sponge test`.